# Android - Resource Bitmap uses more memory than Bitmap from file

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap

I noticed something odd. If I open an image (1.6mb) from Drawable Resource, the app crashes with the `OutOfMemory` error, however, if I open the same image which is saved on SD Card, the app does not crash.

What is the effect of the two?

**Solution:**

Place images in **/drawable-nodpi** folder and not **/drawable**

**Cause:**

> pictures in "/drawable" generic folder are considered by the system like "/drawable/mdpi". So the images are resized when used by the system, causing the OutOfMemory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out :

> I had all the pictures in "/drawable" generic folder that is
>   considered by the system like "/drawable/mdpi", so when I were running
>   in devices with hdpi or more the images were resized, and became too
>   big which cause OutOfMemoryException!

from:
[Android setBackgroundResource cause out of memory excepiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096061/android-setbackgroundresource-cause-out-of-memory-excepiton)

you think this might be your case?

Comment: That is perfect. It was indeed being resized and causing `OutOfMemory` error.

Comment: Thanks man! I was very surprised to see in DDMS 4 times more memory usage by bitmap :)