# Android Memory Leak - setBackgroundDrawable - with images

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

When a user clicks a button, i keep switching the background of a layout like this in Activity code:

```
...
mylayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));//On First click
mylayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));//On Second Click
mylayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img10));//On 10th Click
...
mylayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));//On 11th Click 1st image again and so on.
```

I have 10 images which i keep rotating.
**Soon, it causes OutOfMemory exception.** What am i doing wrong?

If it matters in my manifest file i have:

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

**EDIT 1**
Average size of the image is: 50K
Average dimension of the image is: 600x450
All images img1, img2 etc.. are jpeg images

**Solution Update**
Reducing image dimensions to 300x200 resolved the issue. The memory requirements went down significantly by this single change.

Comment: when ever you showing the more images in your application you have to handle images using image loader task when you are showing all at a time size exceeds heap size so that outofmemory exception arises

Comment: What size are the images?

Comment: background drawables means it may be more than 800x1280 images so thats why he is getting out of memory @Simon

Comment: That's what I'm thinking.  But, he could be using smaller and upscaling?

Comment: go through the [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) from developer site for showing large images in efficient manner

Comment: hareesh145> Thanks...Could you pls post your suggestion of reducing image dimensions as a 'Answer' - so that i can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be happening because your image resources are in `drawable` folder; which is equivalent to drawable-mdpi. And your device might be something other than `mdpi`.

So, either provide images for all the screed densities you are gonna support. Or, put images in `drawable-nodpi`, so your images will not be resized. Hence no `OutOfMemoryException`.

[Referred from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176049/609782)

Comment: Thankyou Darpan, yes that reduced the memory footprint somewhat, but not enough. Must try on devices of varying sizes to see its benefits completely.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Bitmap.recycle() if you can change your Drawable with Bitmap.

Hope This will help

Comment: try this  Bitmap bit= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.large_icon);    user_image.setImageBitmap(bit);

Answer (score 0):

Each bitmap with dimension 600x450 has size of 600*450*4 = 1 080 000 bytes (1 MB) in RAM.
You should load so large bitmaps in another way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.img1);
myLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap));
```

And **before** changing background of the view you have to do

```
Drawable background = myLayout.getBackground();
if (background != null && background instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
    myLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) background;
    bd.getBitmap().recycle();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou fRoStBiT - i tried this, but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think changing background layout so frequently is a good idead. I suggest that you could use `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` as first item. Then everytime you need to change your background, you can change your `ImageView` with some cached library such as: [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)